# How do I reference an existing instance of a model in a nested Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm attempting to build a recipe-keeper app with three primary models:

**Recipe** - The recipe for a particular dish 
**Ingredient** - A list of ingredients, validated on uniqueness 
**Quantity** - A join table between Ingredient and Recipe that also reflects the amount of a particular ingredient required for a particular recipe.

I'm using a nested form (see below) that I constructed using an awesome Railscast on Nested Forms ([Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), [Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)) for inspiration. (My form is in some ways more complex than the tutorial due to the needs of this particular schema, but I was able to make it work in a similar fashion.)

However, when my form is submitted, any and all ingredients listed are created anew—and if the ingredient already exists in the DB, it fails the uniqueness validation and prevents the recipe from being created. Total drag.

**So my question is:** Is there a way to submit this form so that if an ingredient exists whose name matches one of my ingredient-name fields, it references the existing ingredient instead of attempting to create a new one with the same name?

Code specifics below...

---

In `Recipe.rb`:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :directions, :quantities_attributes,
                  :ingredient_attributes

  has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities, allow_destroy: true
```

In `Quantity.rb`:

```
class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recipe_id, :ingredient_id, :amount, :ingredient_attributes

  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
```

And in `Ingredient.rb`:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, through: :quantities
```

Here's my nested form that displays at `Recipe#new`:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
  <%= render 'recipe_form_errors' %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>

  <div id='ingredients'>
    <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |ff| %>
      <div class='ingredient_fields'>
        <%= ff.fields_for :ingredient_attributes do |fff| %>
          <%= fff.label :name %>
          <%= fff.text_field :name %> 
        <% end %>
        <%= ff.label :amount %>
        <%= ff.text_field :amount, size: "10" %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)" %><br>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Add ingredient', "new_ingredient_button", id: 'new_ingredient' %> 
  </div><br>

  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 4, columns: 100 %><br>
  <%= f.label :directions %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :directions, rows: 4, columns: 100 %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The `link_to` and `link_to_function` are there to allow the addition and removal of quantity/ingredient pairs on the fly, and were adapted from the Railscast mentioned earlier. They could use some refactoring, but work more or less as they should.

---

**Update:** Per Leger's request, here's the relevant code from `recipes_controller.rb`. In the `Recipes#new` route, `3.times { @recipe.quantities.build }` sets up three blank quantity/ingredient pairs for any given recipe; these can be removed or added to on the fly using the "Add ingredient" and "remove" links mentioned above.

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    3.times { @recipe.quantities.build }
    @quantity = Quantity.new
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])

    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put the logic of ingredients match into view - it's duty of `Recipe#create` to create proper objects before passing 'em to Model. Pls share the relevant code for controller

Few notes before coming to code:

1. I use Rails4@ruby2.0, but tried to write Rails3-compatible code.
2. `attr_acessible` was deprecated in Rails 4, so strong parameters are used instead. If you ever think to upgrade your app, just go with strong parameters from the beginning.
3. Recommend to make `Ingredient` low-cased to provide uniform appearance on top of case-insensitivity

**OK, here we go:**

Remove `attr_accessible` string in `Recipe.rb`, `Quantity.rb` and `Ingredient.rb`.

Case-insensitive, low-cased `Ingredient.rb`:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.name.downcase! } # to simplify search and unified view
  validates :name, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, through: :quantities
end
```

`<div id='ingredients'>` part of adjusted form to create/update Recipe:

```
<%= f.fields_for :quantities do |ff| %>
  <div class='ingredient_fields'>
    <%= ff.fields_for :ingredient do |fff| %>
      <%= fff.label :name %>
      <%= fff.text_field :name, size: "10" %>
    <% end %>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Add ingredient', "new_ingredient_button", id: 'new_ingredient' %>
```

We should use `:ingredient` from `Quantity` nested_attributes and Rails will add up `_attributes`-part while creating `params`-hash for further mass assignment. It allows to use same form in both new and update actions. For this part works properly association should be defined in advance. See adjusted `Recipe#new` bellow.

and finally `recipes_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  3.times do
    @recipe.quantities.build #initialize recipe -> quantities association
    @recipe.quantities.last.build_ingredient #initialize quantities -> ingredient association
  end
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)    
  prepare_recipe

  if @recipe.save ... #now all saved in proper way
end

def update
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  @recipe.attributes = recipe_params
  prepare_recipe    

  if @recipe.save ... #now all saved in proper way
end

private 
def prepare_recipe
  @recipe.quantities.each do |quantity|
    # do case-insensitive search via 'where' and building SQL-request
    if ingredient = Ingredient.where('LOWER(name) = ?', quantity.ingredient.name.downcase).first
      quantity.ingredient_id = quantity.ingredient.id = ingredient.id
    end
  end
end

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(
    :name,
    :description,
    :directions,
    :quantities_attributes => [
      :id,
      :amount,
      :_destroy,
      :ingredient_attributes => [
        #:id commented bc we pick 'id' for existing ingredients manually and for new we create it
        :name
  ]])
end
```

In `prepare_recipe` we do the following things:

1. Find ID of ingredient with given name
2. Set foreign_key `quantity.ingredient_id` to ID
3. Set `quantity.ingredient.id` to ID (think what happens if you don't do that and change ingredient name in Recipe)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the response--I've added the relevant controller code to the bottom of my original post. Duly noted, regarding logic in the view, but I'm not sure which lines are the offending ones. I wanted to make sure that a user could add ingredients and their quantities when creating a recipe, and I tried to limit the code to just what was required for the form.

Comment: How do i populate the ingredient fields when updating a recipe? The snippet above doesn't seem to be working. (Rails 4.1.4)

Comment: Also, how do i query quantity? Is there a way to map it to ingredient? i.e. @recipe.ingredient[1].quantity ?

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer.  I was able to adapt it to my application.