# Rails 4, double-nested models and strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and began with rails 4 right away.

I have sucessfully nested a Recipe and a Ingredient model so that they can be added in the same form. Next I want to nest quantity within ingredient so that that aswell can be added within the same form. Everything seems to be working fine up until when the quantity of the ingredient is about to be inserted in the database and from this i believe there is something wrong with the strong params in the recipes_controller. But i will post the full code below.
I am using simple_form for the forms.

Thankful for any help!

Here are my models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :desc, presence: true
end


class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

Here is the recipes_controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    3.times do 
      ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.build
      1.times {ingredient.quantities.build }
    end
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe].permit(:title, :desc, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :recipe_id, :name, :_destroy, quantities_attributes: [:id, :ingredient_id, :amount, :unit, :_destroy]]))

    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end


  def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    if @recipe.update(params[:recipe].permit(:title, :desc))
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy

    redirect_to recipes_path
  end





  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :desc, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :recipe_id, :name, :_destroy, quantities_attributes: [:id, :ingredient_id, :amount, :unit, :_destroy]])
    end
end
```

Then i use simple form to create a form for recipe, ingredient and quantity through partials.

_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>


    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :desc %>



    <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>

    <%= render "ingredient_fields", :f => builder %>


    <% end %>

    <p class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add ingredient', f, :ingredients %>
    <p class="links">
    <%= f.error :base%>
    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Which renders from _ingredients_fields:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Ingredient" %>



    <%= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |builder| %>

    <%= render "quantities_fields", :f => builder %>

    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
</div>
```

which renders from _quantities_fields: **[EDITED]**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :amount %>
    <%= f.input :unit %>
</div>
```

Trying to add new recipes result in the following log statement:

```
Started POST "/recipes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-29 14:15:40 +0100
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t6LKgDLwAxaU9xo2ipyCM+j1yfVF9WrI8AoGTX+gRkw=", "recipe"=>{"title"=>"Pancakes", "desc"=>"Tasty", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Milk", "quantities_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"amount"=>"1", "unit"=>"Cup"}}, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Recipe"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (3.5ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "recipes" ("created_at", "desc", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 13:15:40 UTC +00:00], ["desc", "Tasty"], ["title", "Pancakes"], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 13:15:40 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "ingredients" ("created_at", "name", "recipe_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 13:15:40 UTC +00:00], ["name", "Milk"], ["recipe_id", 27], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Oct 2013 13:15:40 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (7.8ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://www.projectcookbook.dev/recipes/27
Completed 302 Found in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 11.7ms)
```

Comment: Perhaps [form object pattern](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects) is a good way to solve complex ActiveRecord nested attributes problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're using similar render for _quantities and _ingredients partials, which is wrong. In _quantities_field you don't need

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :quantities do |builder| %>
<%= render "quantities_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

AND should adjust

```
<%= f.input :name, label: "Quantity" %>
```

in _quantities_fields.

**UPD**

I think the problem is in `:reject_if`-clause at Ingredient model. It should be

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:amount].blank? }
```

bc here you specify conditions for Quantity, not for Ingredient

On code styling:
1) In controller it's better to use relevant name of private method for strong parameters: `recipe_params` instead of `post_params` and then use it for creation of new Recipe `@recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)`

2) Current associations between Recipe, Ingredient and Quantity will lead to Ingredient duplication in case two Recipes use similar one. The reason is `belongs_to`, which define single association. Try another approach (bellow).

BTW. recently I've answered on the similar question. Check it out: [How do I reference an existing instance of a model in a nested Rails form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574130/how-do-i-reference-an-existing-instance-of-a-model-in-a-nested-rails-form)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i wrote in the code wrong in my question, mistakingly copying the same code from _ingredient_fields. I edited this now and wrote the real code that i have been working with. So that was not what caused the problem.

Comment: also, I noted that in the previous question that you recommended, he used a slightly different structure between the models, connecting recipe and ingredient through quantity. But i dont think that is whats is causing my problem or is it? Thankful for any help!

Comment: Yepp, the problem is in Ingredient model, not in the form

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are missing in this part

`<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |f| %>`

it should be

`<%= simple_nested_form_for @recipe do |f| %>`